# Accesing pointer of a structure from another structure

Tags: c, pointers

I have arrived at memory leak after i allocate into a structure

```
  struct List {
        struct node fNode;
  };

  struct node {
        int key;
  };

  void listInit(struct List * fList)
  {
        struct node * temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        nodeInit(temp); // set value or something
        fList->fnode = *temp;
  }

  void listEmpty(struct List * flist)
  {
        nodeEmpty(&flist->fnode);
        memset(&flist->fnode, 0, sizzeof(struct node);
        free(&flist->fnode);
  }
```

I didn't realize that the &flist->fnode adress is not the same as the temp adress returned by malloc. How do i access the adress again from the struct List? And i can't change the atribute into a pointer, it has to be structure itself.

Comment: This: `free(&flist->fnode)` is *guaranteed* to be wrong, as there is no way an address returned from `operator &` is one generated from a standard allocator function in C. The fact is, neither `struct List`, nor `struct node`, have pointer members. I highly suspect an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) based on what this code looks like and the question/conditions your stating. What *problem* is this trying to solve?

Comment: I need a way to get the pointer from the malloc so i can properly free the alocated struct.

Comment: You `List` structure has no place to store such a pointer, and you've already stated you cannot change the structures (though I sincerely doubt these are the "real" structures, as they are near-pointless as is). In short, with what you've shown, you can't get there from here. The `malloc` you have is pointless unless the goal is to leak memory, *because* there is no place to retain the address it returns.

Comment: So that means the only way i can do it is by creating new global variable for storing pointers?

Comment: I couldn't say either way. We still don't know the actual problem being worked on. *Not* the problems you're having with your solution; the actual problem your solution is trying to solve. As is (which isn't much), one thing is certain, that `malloc` is wrong. Indeed *any* dynamic allocation is wrong unless you have a means to retain the address(es) generated from it.

Comment: @ZergOvermind - You need to post a complete example. The posted code doesn't tell us what you are trying. We don't know how the functions are called and we don't know what the `nodeInit`and `nodeEmpty` do. So we can't help.

Comment: Your malloc just leaks memory ... get rid of it and do `nodeInit(&fList->fnode)`

Comment: lisEmpty deallocates whatever the list stores, so nodeEmpty does the same. and the only problem in here is how to properly deallocated the node, i can't change any of it and teh structures are supposed to be allocated.

Comment: No pointers, no list. Or at least nothing more then a 1-node-only list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to allocate `node` inside the list. It is a normal variable, not a pointer, and gets allocated along side the list. It's enough to call `InitNode(&fList.node)` and it should work.

However, perhaps there's some more design work which needs to happen, since it doesn't get you anything to have a regular node inside the list.

Comment: As i already mentioned, i can not change the structures. And this is just an example, the actuall node contains more info, it works as linked list.

Comment: Fair enough. The first part of the response still is valid.

Answer (score 1):

If the structures are set, you aren't supposed to malloc the node, but rather initialize it as part of initializing the list:

```
void listInit(struct List * fList) // Must be pointing to a valid list already.
{
  nodeInit(&fList->fNode);
}
```

The use case that your homework has in mind is this:

```
struct List myList; // Automatic ("stack") variable.
listInit(&myList); // The function initializes the variable, it doesn't allocate it
```